# How to retrieve list of objects in sequence order that is passed from an ArrayList in MongoDB using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I'm trying to retrieve list of object in sequence order from User collection that is passed in ArrayList using $in operator. But I don't get the objects in order.

```
List<String> companyProfiledb = mongotemplate.findDistinct(query, "userID", CompanyProfile.class, String.class);
System.out.println(companyProfiledb);
Query userquery = new Query(Criteria.where("userID").in(companyProfiledb));
System.out.println(userquery);
List<User>  userdb = mongotemplate.find(userquery, User.class, "User");
System.out.println(userdb);
```

When I print in console -

ArrayList of userID from CompanyProfile:

`System.out.println(companyProfiledb);` ---> [3, 1, 5]

Query for ArrayList of userID using $in operator:

`System.out.println(userquery);` ---> Query: { "userID" : { "$in" : ["3", "1", "5"] } }, Fields: { }, Sort:{ }

After retrieving list of documents from the database:

`System.out.println(userdb);` ---> [User(userID=1), User(userID=3), User(userID=5)]

*I expect the output from the list as*

`[User(userID=3), User(userID=1), User(userID=5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Add sorting in your query

```
Query userquery = new Query(Criteria.where("userID").in(companyProfiledb)).with(new Sort("_id", "-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the sort from the query

Query: { "userID" : { "$in" : ["3", "1", "5"] } }, Fields: { }